# i have an array i want to generate randomly on page refresh

Tags: php

i have an array example:

```
Array
(
[0] => 5c832a3fec3a6
[1] => 5c832a3fdbe90
[2] => 5c832a3fc6335
[3] => 5c832a3fb080d
[4] => 5c832a3f89d5b
)
```

i want to result like this when i refersh my page.

first time refersh

```
Array
(
[0] => 5c832a3fc6335
[1] => 5c832a3f89d5b
[2] => 5c832a3fec3a6
[3] => 5c832a3fb080d
[4] => 5c832a3fdbe90
)
```

in second time refresh

```
Array
(
[0] => 5c832a3fc6335
[1] => 5c832a3fb080d
[2] => 5c832a3f89d5b
[3] => 5c832a3fdbe90
[4] => 5c832a3fec3a6
)
```

it means every time new random array in result.

Comment: ok ... so at least make an attempt.

Comment: take a look at [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

Comment: I had tried "shuffle" but did not get the result.

Comment: Well, show us what you tried, tell us what was wrong with the results that you got and what the result you expected was, and then we might be able to help you. At present there is not enough information in your question to be able to give you an answer.

Comment: Your question seems Unclear.  Why is `shuffle()` not an ideal solution?

Comment: If you can improve your question and clarify why `shuffle()` will not do, your question can be reopened.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As an alternative to [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php), you can also use [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php):

```
$array = [
0 => "5c832a3fec3a6",
1 => "5c832a3fdbe90",
2 => "5c832a3fc6335",
3 => "5c832a3fb080d",
4 => "5c832a3f89d5b",
];

while(!empty($array)){
    $key = rand(0,4);
    if(key_exists($key, $array)){
        $new_order[] = $array[$key];
    }
    unset($array[$key]);
}

var_dump($new_order);
```

**Caveat**

This is a costly exercise, so while it's relatively harmless for small arrays like this, I would probably stick to [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php).

Comment: While I gave you an answer because I sort of figured out what you wanted to achieve, it's better form for the OP to try something, and if it doesn't work, share what they tried and ask people here to help them figure out where they went wrong. Otherwise StackOverflow just becomes a place where people ask others to write bits of code for them.